# Gradle build - not able to import org.json

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I have a problem where I’m trying to include `org.json` as a dependency in my gradle/spring boot project.  In my build.gradle I have

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile("org.json:json:20141113")
}
```

But in the editor window it looks like IntelliJ is not able to import org.json - it’s unable to find the package

[image]

[image]

What’s weird is that I can run the gradle ‘build’ task without errors in IntelliJ, and I can run

```
./gradlew clean build && java -jar build/libs/MyApp-0.1.0.jar
```

and it works fine.

Is this a ‘fat jar’ problem?  I’m not sure it is because `org.json` is definitely not in my class path on the command line.  Any advice appreciated.

Comment: try `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`

Comment: I've tried Invalidate Caches as you suggested, then rebuilding.  After the rebuild the editor still looks the same.  What's weird is that it rebuilds fine.

Comment: Have you reimported the gradle project in IntelliJ after adding the dependency (i.e. clicked on the reload icon at the top of the gradle tool window)?

Comment: That worked!  Thanks!

Answer (score 41):

I was able to successfully download json in my gradle dependencies:

```
implementation 'org.json:json:20171018'
```

Comment: that fixes the problem. You can find the latest vesrion here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

At the moment of writing it is 20180813

Comment: And it is now 20200518.

Answer (score 10):

As some mentioned, [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) provides snippet for different Build systems.
After you choose your desired version, in the middle of the page, select `Gradle` as build system, copy and paste the snippet in your `build.gradle` file, section `dependencies` in your java project.

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json
compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180813'
```

Comment: Can you explain how this solves the problem, and the reasoning behind it? This would make the answer more useful in similar situations.

Comment: I gradle, after you enter the lines above, don't you need to do a jarLibs 'xxx.xxx:xxx:xxx'  entry: ? How would that look?  And also an uberJar?  How would that be done for org.json?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your dependency configuration is set correct in your build.gradle, especially important when running plugins like a test framework.

For example, I wanted to use JsonObject in a Gatling test. I needed to add the json dependency as follows

```
dependencies {
  gatlingImplementation 'org.json:json:20230227'
}
```

To see the available configurations run

```
gradle -q dependencies
```